# Removing symfony projects

Tags: linux, symfony

I know there's been plenty of questions about removing the AcmeDemoBundle that comes with Symfony, however I wanted to check with you all that I'm understanding the whole Symfony ethos correctly:

For example, I have three projects each created with symfony (eg `symfony new Project3`):

```
/home/<username>/Project1
                /Project2
                /Project3
```

If I no longer want Project3, can I simply delete the directory (eg `rmdir Project3`) and not have to worry about any associations or conflicts with other projects or apache/mysql etc?

Comment: Yes. Each project contains separate instances of the Symfony framework within the `vendors` folder, hence each project is "self-contained"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symfony uses bundles to add and remove functionality to a Symfony project.

I would say yes to your answer, but only if you are certain that Project1 and/or Project2 don't use any of the bundles present in Project3.

While it's possible that Project1 and/or Project2 use a bundle present in Project3 it's probably not the case since you would have to include a hardlink to that bundle in your Project1/Project2 configuration.

Most of the time a bundle would be something you included from either a packagist archive, a github repo or something like that.

Comment: Thanks @Kishin for the clarification - that makes it crystal clear regarding the bundles across projects - good to know!